# What's the most efficient use of computing resources when reading from one file and writing to another? line by line or in a batch to a list?

Tags: python, performance, csv, text, etl

I'm reading line by line from a text file and manipulating the string to then be written to a csv file.

I can think of two best ways to do this (and I welcome other ideas or modifications):

1. Read, process single line into a list, and go straight to writing the line.

```
linelist = []

with open('dirty.txt', 'r') as dirty_text:
   with open('clean.csv', 'w') as clean_csv:
      cleancsv_writer = csv.writer(clean_csv, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
         for line in dirty_text:
            #Parse fields into list, replacing the previous list item with a new string that is a comma-separated row.
            #Write list item into clean.csv.
```

2. Read and process the lines into a list (until reaching the size limit of a list), then writing the list to the csv in one big batch. Repeat until end of file (but I'm leaving out the loop for this example).

```
linelist = []
seekpos = 0

with open('dirty.txt', 'r') as dirty_text:
   for line in dirty_text:
      #Parse fields into list until the end of the file or the end of the list's memory space, such that each list item is a string that is a comma-separated row.
      #update seek position to come back to after this batch, if looping through multiple batches

with open('clean.csv', 'a') as clean_csv:
   cleancsv_writer = csv.writer(clean_csv, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
      #write list into clean.csv, each list item becoming a comma-separated row.

#This would likely be a loop for bigger files, but for my project and for simplicity, it's not necessary.
```

Which process is the most efficient use of resources?

In this case, I'm assuming nobody (human or otherwise) needs access to either file during this process (though I would gladly hear discussion about efficiency in that case).

I'm also assuming a list demands less resources than a dictionary.

Memory use is my primary concern. My hunch is that the first process uses the least memory because the list never gets longer than one item, so the maximum memory it uses at any given moment is less than that of the second process which maxes out the list memory. But, I'm not sure how dynamic memory allocation works in Python, and you have two file objects open at the same time in the first process.

As for power usage and total time it takes, I'm not sure which process is more efficient. My hunch is that with multiple batches, the second option would use more power and take more time because it opens and closes the files at each batch.

As for code complexity and length, the first option seems like it will turn out simpler and shorter.

Other considerations?

Which process is best?

Is there a better way? Ten better ways?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Reading all the data into memory is inefficient because it uses more memory than necessary.

You can trade some CPU for memory; the program to read everything into memory will have a single, very simple main loop; but the main bottleneck will be the I/O channel, so it really won't be faster. Regardless of how fast the code runs, any reasonable implementation will spend most of its running time waiting for the disk.

If you have enough memory, reading the entire file into memory will work fine. Once the data is bigger than your available memory, performance will degrade ungracefully (i.e. the OS will start swapping regions of memory out to disk and then swap them back in when they are needed again; in the worst case, this will basically grind the system to a halt, a situation called thrashing). The main reason to prefer reading and writing a line at a time is that the program will perform without degradation even when you scale up to larger amounts of data.

Answer (score 2):

I/O is already buffered; just write what looks natural, and let the file-like objects and the operating system take care of the actual disk reads and writes.

```
with open('dirty.txt', 'r') as dirty_text:
    with open('clean.csv', 'w') as clean_csv:
        cleancsv_writer = csv.writer(clean_csv, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        for line in dirty_text:
            row = some_function(line)
            cleancsv_writer.writerow(row)
```

If all the work of cleaning up a line is abstracted away by `some_function`, you don't even need the `for` loop.

```
with open('dirty.txt', 'r') as dirty_text,\
    with open('clean.csv', 'w') as clean_csv:
        cleancsv_writer = csv.writer(clean_csv, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        cleancsv_writer.writerows(some_function(line) for line in dirty_text))
```